# R shiny ggplot2 error 'Results must be all atomic, or all data frames'

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I get inconsistent errors with my shiny app and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. This is the most common error.

```
Error: Results must be all atomic, or all data frames.
```

The shiny app basically allows the user to chose 1 or more files, then reads those files (having differing number of columns), merges them using `rbind.fill()` (`plyr`) and then to `melt()` and then to `ggplot2`. ggplot2 plots one below the other using faceting.

The errors are same on my computer running Win 8, R 3.2.0, plyr_1.8.2    ggplot2_1.0.1, shiny_0.12.0 and on the Server running Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.2.0,  shiny_0.12.0, plyr_1.8.2, ggplot2_1.0.1.

The code is below.

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Error test App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("data", label = "Select files",
                  choices = c("file1.txt","file2.txt", "file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt"),
                  selected=NULL,
                  multiple=T)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("plotoutput",width="100%",height="100%")
    )
  )
))

#server.R
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

options(shiny.trace=TRUE)

#plotfunction
#reads selected files and transforms them into a dataframe compatible to be read by ggplot and the plot is returned
plotfunction <- function(files = NULL, na.rm = TRUE)
{
  #loop to process selected files
  plist <- vector("list",length=length(files))
  for (i in 1:length(files))
  {
    df1 <- read.delim(file = files[i],header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)

    k <- ncol(df1)
    df1$Ind <- factor(1:nrow(df1))
    df1$Num <- factor(rep(i, nrow(df1)))
    plist[[i]] <- df1
  }

  #MOST LIKELY ERROR BLOCK ====================================================
  #combine list to one dataframe 
  df2 <- plyr::rbind.fill(plist)

  #melt
  df3 <- reshape2::melt(df2, id.var = c("Ind", "Num"))

  #ggplot
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = Ind, y = value, fill = variable))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, space = 0, stat = "identity", position = "stack", na.rm = na.rm)+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
    facet_grid(Num~.)+
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
    theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(), 
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0), "lines"),
          strip.text=element_blank())

  #MOST LIKELY ERROR BLOCK ====================================================

  return(p)
}

#shinyserver
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #renderimage
  output$plotoutput <- renderImage({
    fnvalidate <- function(input) {if(is.null(input)) print("Select one or more files.")}
    validate(fnvalidate(input=input$data))

    sp1 <- plotfunction(files=input$data)

    png("plot.png", height=2, width=6, res=200, units="cm")
    print(sp1)
    dev.off()

    return(list(src = "plot.png",
                contentType = "image/png",
                width = round((6*200)/2.54, 0),
                height = round((1*length(input$data)*200)/2.54, 0),
                alt = "plot"))

    },deleteFile=T)

})
```

Comment: Thanks for going through the effort to provide all these links, but is it not possible to provide a small simple reproducible example inline? It'll be much easier for us to attempt

Comment: hmmm.. I guess I could, but its a lot of code and it might be rather long. And if I minimize the code too much, the error is not reproducible.

Comment: That's what I meant, try to find out the chunk of code where the error happens and what's the smallest code that causes it... if you can't then that's fine, just thought it'd make it easier to help

Comment: FYI, the app seems to work correctly using either plyr_1.8.1 or the development version of plyr (1.8.2.9000) instead of plyr_1.8.2.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. That's the most breakthrough I had in a long time. I upgraded to the latest github version of plyr. Unfortunately I get this new error now which seems to also stem from the ggplot fn when it prints.
Error in .Call("loop_apply", as.integer(n), f, env) : 
  "loop_apply" not resolved from current namespace (plyr)

Comment: I can't reproduce (using Win 7 with the same R/package versions you list above) - did you change anything else in your scripts?  Your new error makes it seem like plyr might still be your stumbling block.

Comment: I'm having the same error. Updating to latest plyr on github didn't help. `"loop_apply" not resolved from current namespace (plyr)`

Comment: @Roy @Juancentro FYI, plyr_1.8.3 is now on CRAN.  A few other things you might try:  See if you can get things to work if you load all three packages (ggplot2, plyr, reshape2) via `library()` within `server.r` instead of using functions from namespace (e.g., remove `plyr::rbind.fill()` and just use `rbind.fill`).  Look at your `sessionInfo()` to see what version of plyr is loaded into the namespace and/or attached.  Consider adding the `sessionInfo()` results to your question.

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself after further updates. I am currently on plyr_1.8.3.9000. I don't think I tried plyr_1.8.3 from CRAN. If anyone is looking for an alternative to `rbind.fill()`, I found that `ldply()` seems to give the same results. Although `rbind.fill()` is a bit faster. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad it's finally working.  Also see `bind_rows` from package dplyr as alternative to `rbind.fill`.

Comment: @Juancentro See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352789/keep-hitting-the-error-loop-apply-not-resolved-from-current-namespace-plyr) for a possible solution to the loop_apply error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with plyr, which is probably going to get fixed in the next R update. Until then you can fix it following these steps:

1. Install platform specific development tools:

   - Windows: Download and install Rtools33.exe from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
   - Ubuntu or Debian based Linux: sudo apt-get install r-base-devel
   - Rpm-based Linux: install r-devel
   - Mac: install the Xcode command line tools from https://developer.apple.com/downloads
2. Install devtools

   install.packages("devtools")
3. Compile and install the fixed version of plyr

   devtools::install_github("hadley/plyr")
4. RESTART R/Rstudio