# Keep hitting the error ""loop_apply" not resolved from current namespace (plyr)" in ggplot2 with example codes

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

i keep hitting this error today and I already download the plyr from github but it still doesn't work. I restarted R-studio even my PC after installing plyr..

[image]

Comment: i did load after I found that it could not find function ggplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the problem may be due to a change made to the way R resolves references to external DLLs, as mentioned halfway through the thread [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/question-re-error-message-package-error-quot-functionName-quot-not-resolved-from-current-namespace-td4663892.html).

Adding the parameter **PACKAGE="plyr"** to the **.Call** function call on line 12 of **R/loop_apply.R** in the source (clone from github), and then installing the package from that source (**install.packages("*<path to plyr source>*", type="source", repos=NULL)**) seems to fix it.

Comment: It happened also to me and thanks to your answer I could fix it just re-installing plyr from sources...